# \uline not work for command arguments

Tags: ulem

I try to use `\uline` from the `ulem` package. Moreover, I need a command to carry some text. Unfortunately, `\uline` doesn't wrap the text carried by the command automatically.

**Code:**

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

I think \expandafter should help, but I'm unfamiliar with it.

**Remark:** I cannot enter Chinese in the code, so I use a picture instead. And the code is compiled with xelatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, `\expandafter` solves the problem.

**Code:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `soul` for underlining?

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\sometext}{%
This is a slightly long title for testing the document class. This is a slightly long title for testing the document class.}

\begin{document}
\ul{%
This is a slightly long title for testing the document class. This is a slightly long title for testing the document class.}% work

\ul\sometext% works
\end{document}
```

[image: underlining more easily]

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but it had another problem, i.e. it does not work with Chinese. I am not sure whether I should ask a new question.