# \uline{} does not work correctly with long non-English lines

Tags: line-breaking, ulem, text, russian

I have encountered with situation that `\uline` does not break correctly non-English lines. I think that problem may be in extra-libraries that I use.

For, example I work with Russian document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{сельско-хо-зяйствен-ный}
\begin{document}

\uline{ Большой длинный русский текст, который не отображается нормально, по каким-то причинам, не помогает никакая магия для этого, особенно проблемы с длинными словами, такими как сельскохозяйственный и прочими длинносочленными словами.}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that sometimes it works correctly, but sometimes it is not. Is there any way to fix it ? Even when I try to set rules for separating words it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no problem with `soulutf8`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\hyphenation{сельско-хо-зяйствен-ный}

\begin{document}

\ul{Большой длинный русский текст, который не отображается нормально, по каким-то причинам, не помогает
никакая магия для этого, особенно проблемы с длинными словами, такими как сельскохозяйственный и
прочими длинносочленными словами.}

\parbox[t]{0pt}{%
\ul{Большой длинный русский текст сельскохозяйственный}
}

\end{document}
```

Avoid `hyphenat`.

[image]

Comment: I have tried `soul` package, but it didn't work with russian text, I thought it is because some troubles with package. Thank you!

Comment: @DmitriyChasovskoy For compatibility with UTF-8, one has to use `soulutf8`.

Comment: Another solution if you use commands: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270286/uline-not-work-for-command-arguments